# Problem to add element to matrix in if-else condition in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm writing a simple program to implement Artificial Neural Network to recognize handwritten characters using Matlab. I used following code to set Target data according to different characters.

Here is a part of code:

```
load('dataset.mat')

Target_Set=zeros(2,400); %Initialize Target array with 0s

%Set dimensions to resize
h = 50;
w = 45;
imgSize = h*w;

for j=1:4
    for i=1:10
        for k=1:10
            Temp_Struct = struct('im',imresize(handwriting(i,j,k).im,[h,w]));
            n = 100*(j-1) + 10*(i-1) + k;
            P_Set(1:imgSize,n) = reshape(Temp_Struct.im,[imgSize,1]); 

            %Set Target patterns...
            if (j==1) %When character I                   %   Target Patterns...
Line 19========>Target_Set(0,n) = 1;                     %    I   J   K   L
                Target_Set(1,n) = 0;                     %    0   1   0   1
            elseif(j==2) %When character J               %    0   0   1   1
                Target_Set(0,n) = 1;
                Target_Set(1,n)=0;
            elseif(j==3) %When character K            
                Target_Set(0,n) = 0;
                Target_Set(1,n)=1;
            else %When character L       
                Target_Set(0,n) = 1;
                Target_Set(1,n)=1;            
            end;

        end;
    end;
end;
```

When I run this, I got some error like this.

[image]

I couldn't understand why that kind of error occur in line 19. Welcome for any help.

Comment: Please copy-paste the error message as text into your question. Images are not accessible for everyone and they are not searchable. This makes the question much less useful for future visitors. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays in Matlab start at index number 1. So it is complaining about your use of a 0 value as an array index.
It should be correct like this.

```
Target_Set(1,n) = 0;
```